# Find all natural numbers $x,y,z$ such that $x^7+y^7=7^z$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

**Find all natural numbers $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^7+y^7=7^z$.**
Firstly, I note that given that the right hand side only has factors of $7$, it must be odd and so $x^7+y^7$ must be odd i.e $x^7$ and $y^7$ have opposite parity, which then means $x$ and $y$ have opposite parity. Also, I have got the following:
$$
x^7+y^7=7^z \implies x^7+y^7\equiv0\pmod{7}
$$
By Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $x^7\equiv x\pmod{7}$ and similarly for $y$, $y^7\equiv y\pmod{7}$, so then $x^7+y^7\equiv0\pmod{7}\implies x+y\equiv0\pmod{7}$. I have also factorised $x^7+y^7$:
$$
x^7+y^7=(x+y)(x^6-x^5y+x^4y^2-x^3y^3+x^2y^4-xy^5+y^6)=7^z
$$
So not only does $7$ divide $x+y$, we also have that $7\mid(x^6-x^5y+x^4y^2-x^3y^3+x^2y^4-xy^5+y^6)$ but at this point I feel like I am just not making any real progress. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In fact, from your last equation you get a stronger statement that $x+y=7^k$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing there is no triplet of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ satisfying $a^7+b^7=7^c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348757/showing-there-is-no-triplet-of-positive-integers-a-b-c-satisfying-a7b7-7) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E7%2By%5E7%3D7%5Ez%24&p=1). Note I thought there would be a duplicate yesterday, but Approach0 wasn't working then & my site searches were unsuccessful. Note also my answer, that I've now deleted, is quite similar to this [one](/a/1348787) to that other question.

Comment: Do not confuse $7^z$ with $z^7$. This is not the equation of Fermat's Last Theorem for exponent $7$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Note the OP mentions "Fermat's *Little* Theorem", not "Fermat's *Last* Theorem".

Answer (score 4):

If a solution exists where $7\mid x$ and $7\mid y$ then another solution can be generated by dividing $x$ and $y$ by $7$.

Suppose a solution exists where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers that are not divisible by $7$. We have that $$x^7+y^7=(x+y)\left(x^6-x^5y+x^4y^2-x^3y^3+x^2y^4-xy^5+y^6\right)$$As mentioned in the OP, by Fermat's Little Theorem, $$x^7+y^7\equiv x+y\equiv0\pmod7,$$ so let $x+y=7k$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Since $$x^6-x^5y+x^4y^2-x^3y^3+x^2y^4-xy^5+y^6=(x+y)^6-7xy(x+y)^4+14(xy)^2(x+y)^2-7(xy)^3,$$$x^7+y^7$ can be rewritten as $$\begin{align}&(x+y)\left[(x+y)^6-7xy(x+y)^4+14(xy)^2(x+y)^2-7(xy)^3\right]\\&=(x+y)\left[7^6k^6-7^5k^4xy+2\cdot7^3k^2(xy)^2-7(xy)^3\right]\\&=7(x+y)\left[7^5k^6-7^4k^4xy+2\cdot7^2k^2(xy)^2-(xy)^3\right]\end{align}$$
Since $7\mid7^5k^6$, $7\mid7^4k^4xy$ and $7\mid2\cdot7^2k^2(xy)^2$ but $7\nmid(xy)^3$, $7\nmid7^5k^6-7^4k^4xy+2\cdot7^2k^2(xy)^2-(xy)^3$. However, for $x^7+y^7$ to be a perfect power of $7$, all of its factors must also be perfect powers of $7$ and so $7^5k^6-7^4k^4xy+2\cdot7^2k^2(xy)^2-(xy)^3$ must equal $1$. It follows that $$x^7+y^7=7(x+y)$$If $x>1$ then $x^7>7x$, so at least one of $x$ and $y$ must be $1$. If $x=1$, $y^7-7y-6=0$, which has no positive integer solutions.

Therefore, there are no solutions where $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers and the only possible natural number solutions are if one of $x$ and $y$ is $0$. If $x=0$ then $y^7=7^z$, so $y=7^k\,\forall \,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

This means that the only solutions are $(x,y,z)=(0,7^k,7k),(7^k,0,7k)$.